# SQL Server grouping foiled by case statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

My applications has Bills, which in turn may have multiple line items (billItems).

A Bill may also have a Copay amount, which is added to the total of the line items.

It may also have a Rebill amount, which supercedes the line items altogether.

I have a function which needs to return a total billing amount. Currently, it looks like this:

```
SELECT @billed = (SELECT CASE WHEN b.Rebill=1 THEN ISNULL(b.RebillAmt,0)
        WHEN b.HasCopay=1 THEN ISNULL(SUM(bi.Amount),0) + ISNULL(b.CopayAmt,0)
        ELSE ISNULL(SUM(bi.Amount),0) END AS TotalBilled
    FROM BillItems bi 
        INNER JOIN Bills b ON b.BillID=bi.BillID
        INNER JOIN Procedures p ON p.ProcedureID=b.ProcedureID
    WHERE p.CaseID = @CASEID
    AND     p.StatusID=3
    GROUP BY b.CaseID,b.Rebill,b.RebillAmt,b.HasCopay,b.CopayAmt)
RETURN @billed
```

When there are no copays or rebill amounts, the function returns a single total. However, if there are copay or rebill amounts, the inner SELECT returns a record for each Bill which has either a copay or rebill, and a record with a total for those Bills which have neither a copay or rebill amount.

How should I restate this so that I get a single total billing amount for each "Case"?

(This is a SQL Server 2008 installation.)

Thanks,

Tom

**Here is further information: first, the business purpose and rules.**

Think of a course of medical treatment. For reference, call it a "Case."

Each case will have a series of treatments (Procedures). For a given Procedure, one or more Bills will be received. For each of those Bills, there may be one or more billing line items (BillItems), each of which will have an Amount.

For each Bill, the total final billing amount will be either:

- The total of the Amounts of all related BillItems, or
- if the Bill.HasCopay flag is true, and there is a CopayAmt, the total of all related BillItem Amounts plus the CopayAmt; or
- if the Bill.Rebill flag is true and there is a RebillAmt, the RebillAmt

So if the Bill is to be "rebilled," the RebillAmt is the total billing. If there is a CopayAmt, it is added to the total of the BillItems. Otherwise, we just total the BillItems.

The goal is to aggregate a single total billing amount for a case, based on applying the above rules to each Bill.

The DDLs are below. The Case table has been omitted, because it has many irrelevant fields. Suffice to say, it is represented by the CaseID relationship in the other tables.

The tables are not normalized, in that there are redundant relationships back to the Case. This was purposely done for ease of reporting. You can certainly disagree with the design, but that's the way it is.

The foreign key relationships are not shown in the code below, but from the rules above, it should be apparent that Cases have Procedures which have Bills which have BillItems.

And finally, for clarity the "p.StatusID=3" in the original statement simply identifies Procedures which have been "approved." All others are ignored.

Thanks very much for the help. Hopefully, this will be enough information to make the question more answerable. Here's the code:

```
CREATE TABLE Procedures (
ProcedureID int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
RequestID int NOT NULL,
StatusID int,
ProviderLocationID int DEFAULT ((0)) NOT NULL,
Description varchar(3000),
CPTcodes varchar(500),
Rejected bit DEFAULT ((0)) NOT NULL,
CreateDate datetime DEFAULT (getdate()) NOT NULL,
CreatedByID int,
ChangeDate datetime DEFAULT (getdate()) NOT NULL,
ChangeUserID int,
ApprovalDate datetime,
ApprovalCode varchar(25),
ShowCPTCodes bit DEFAULT ((1)) NOT NULL,
DispositionDate datetime,
PreviouslyApproved bit DEFAULT ((0)) NOT NULL,
SubmissionDate datetime,
DenialDate datetime,
IsPT bit DEFAULT ((0)) NOT NULL,
DenialReason varchar(1000),
PriorProcedure bit DEFAULT ((0)) NOT NULL,
UseCommonTreatmentDates bit DEFAULT ((1)) NOT NULL,
IsComplete bit DEFAULT ((0)) NOT NULL,
CommonTreatmentDate datetime,
TreatmentNoteReceived varchar(25) DEFAULT ('No') NOT NULL,
TreatmentNoteRead bit DEFAULT ((0)) NOT NULL,
TreatmentNoteReceivedDate datetime,
TreatmentNoteReadDate datetime,
InvoiceReceived varchar(25),
InvoiceReceivedDate datetime,
CaseID int DEFAULT ((0)) NOT NULL,
TreatmentDate datetime,
ScheduledDate datetime,
PTRemoved bit DEFAULT ((0)) NOT NULL,
ProviderID int DEFAULT ((0)) NOT NULL,
TherapyGroupID int DEFAULT ((0)) NOT NULL,
SendDemographics bit DEFAULT ((0)) NOT NULL,
SendOrder bit DEFAULT ((0)) NOT NULL,
TreatmentNoteNotNeeded bit DEFAULT ((0)) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (ProcedureID)
```

);

```
CREATE TABLE Bills (
BillID int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
InvoiceID int DEFAULT ((0)),
CaseID int NOT NULL,
ProcedureID int NOT NULL,
TherapyGroupID int DEFAULT ((0)) NOT NULL,
ProviderID int NOT NULL,
Description varchar(1000),
ServiceDescription varchar(255),
BillReferenceNumber varchar(100),
TreatmentDate datetime,
DateBilled datetime,
DateBillReceived datetime,
DateBillApproved datetime,
HasCopay bit DEFAULT ((0)) NOT NULL,
CopayAmt money,
Rebill bit DEFAULT ((0)) NOT NULL,
RebillAmt money,
IncludeInDemand bit DEFAULT ((1)) NOT NULL,
CreateDate datetime DEFAULT (getdate()) NOT NULL,
CreatedByID int,
ChangeDate datetime,
ChangeUserID int,
PRIMARY KEY (BillID)
```

);

```
CREATE TABLE BillItems (
BillItemID int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
BillID int NOT NULL,
ItemDescription varchar(1000),
Amount money,
WillNotBePaid bit DEFAULT ((0)) NOT NULL,
CreateDate datetime DEFAULT (getdate()),
CreatedByID int,
ChangeDate datetime,
ChangeUserID varchar(25),
PRIMARY KEY (BillItemID)
```

);

Comment: Please post the sql to create tables, insert sample rows and show what you expect.

Comment: Like @BoratSagdiyev said, there is not enough information here. You might want to do some form of tricky aggregation or you might just want to get the most recent value. Without knowing more about the process using the function it's hard to give any advice.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
select
    SUM(Amount) as TotalBilled
from (
    select      
        case 
            when b.Rebill = 1 then coalesce(b.RebillAmt, 0)
            when b.HasCopay = 1 then coalesce(bi.Amount, 0) + coalesce(b.CopayAmt, 0)
            else coalesce(bi.Amount, 0)
        end as Amount
    FROM BillItems bi 
        INNER JOIN Bills b ON b.BillID=bi.BillID
        INNER JOIN Procedures p ON p.ProcedureID=b.ProcedureID
    WHERE p.CaseID = @CASEID
        AND p.StatusID=3
) x
```

Comment: I appreciate the answer, but it produces the same results as the original.

Answer (score 0):

I have found at least one way to achieve what I need. Since each combination of Bills and related BillItems could have a total resulting from the totaled amounts of the BillItems, from that total *plus* the copay, or from the rebill amount, each of those possibilities must be examined individually.

And for an accumulation of Bills for a Case, the result of any of those examinations ("Is there a total based on rebilling?") could be an empty recordset.

Thus, I built a solution that involves a combination of COALESCE statements to assure that the examination of any of the possible combinations results in a zero if no records are returned.

The results of examining each of the three possibilities are then added.

Here's my solution. If someone sees a flaw, or a better way, please let me know.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fnTotalBilled]  (@CASEID INT)
RETURNS MONEY AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @billed MONEY

SELECT @billed  = (SELECT COALESCE((SELECT COALESCE(sum(bi.Amount),0)
FROM BillItems bi INNER JOIN Bills b ON b.BillID=bi.BillID
    INNER JOIN Procedures p on p.ProcedureID=b.ProcedureID
WHERE b.CaseID=@CASEID
AND p.StatusID=3
AND b.HasCopay=0
AND b.Rebill=0),0))
+
(SELECT COALESCE((SELECT sum(bi.Amount) + COALESCE(b.CopayAmt,0)
FROM BillItems bi INNER JOIN Bills b ON b.BillID=bi.BillID
    INNER JOIN Procedures p on p.ProcedureID=b.ProcedureID
WHERE b.CaseID=@CASEID
AND p.StatusID=3
AND b.HasCopay=1
GROUP BY b.CaseID,b.CopayAmt),0))
+
(SELECT COALESCE((SELECT sum(COALESCE(b.RebillAmt,0))
FROM Bills b
    INNER JOIN Procedures p on p.ProcedureID=b.ProcedureID
WHERE b.CaseID=@CASEID
AND p.StatusID=3
AND b.Rebill=1),0))

RETURN @billed
END;
```